# Al poner un div padre en FLEX, sus hijos pierden el width original

Tags: javascript, html, flex

Mi problema es que, tengo un div llamado articles que tiene de hijos a varios artículos, pero cuando le pongo display flex (para hacer un carousel con JavaScript), como que se achicharran y no encuentro la forma para que los artículos tengan su width (el que les puse en los styles.css). Había hecho un carousel antes, pero ahora me pasa esto.

```
<div class="articles">
    <i class="fas fa-angle-left" id="btn-carousel-left"></i>
    <div class="article-product">
        <div class="img">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x300" alt="Camisa Roja de Jazmín White">
        </div>
        <div class="info">
            <h3 class="title">Camisa Roja</h3>
            <p class="price">$1500</p>
            <ul>
                <li>3 cuotas sin interés</li>
                <li>Envío gratis</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="article-product">
        <div class="img">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x300" alt="Camisa Roja de Jazmín White">
        </div>
        <div class="info">
            <h3 class="title">Camisa Roja</h3>
            <p class="price">$1500</p>
            <ul>
                <li>3 cuotas sin interés</li>
                <li>Envío gratis</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <i class="fas fa-angle-right" id="btn-carousel-right"></i>
</div>
```

Hay más articulos, pero es mucho codigo para poner acá. Le pongo display: flex al padre.

```
.articles {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    /* grid-template-columns: repeat(1000, 23%);
    gap: 20px; */
    overflow: hidden;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

A los artículos, le puse width: 200px;

```
.article-product {
    width: 200px;
    /* width: var(--article-product-width); */
    margin: 15px 5px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(149, 157, 165, 0.2);
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Sin embargo, cuando se juntan varios article-product, estos pierden el width que les había puesto, como lo puedo arreglar?

Comment: Tal cual como está tu código está bien. Probé y le agregué más `article-product` y no hay problema. Simplemente le agregué `overfloy-x: auto` a `.articles`

Comment: Gracias por responder. A mi no me funciona con overflow-x: auto; Pero pude resolverlo en ponerle a los article-product, en vez de WIDTH, MIN-WIDTH.